# Induction On Frequency Properties Of Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

The title of the question may be a bit misleading, sorry, but I was at a loss of what else to call it.

I have two sequences of integers which are generally quite random, except that the rate at which the terms of the sequence grow is bounded below by at least asymptotic to a linear order and above by at most asymptotic to some higher degree polynomial order. I then add both sequences to get a third sequence.  Say I know that for both sequences there are an infinite number of terms which only occur once. Can I somehow prove that in the third sequence there are an infinite number of terms which only occur once? Also, say I know that in both sequences there are only a finite amount of terms that only occur once. Then can I somehow prove that in the third sequence there are also only a finite amount of terms that occur once?

Would such a proof, if anyone finds any, be able to prove a similar result but with terms which occur twice, thrice, etc?

I have tried in vain to get a start with this problem - I consider it quite difficult. Any help and further thought is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if your first sequence is $$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,\dots$$ and your second sequence is $$4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,\dots$$ Both grow linearly, both have infinitely many terms that occur exactly once, their sum is $$5,5,9,9,13,13,17,17,\dots$$ in which no term occurs exactly once.

On the other hand, if your sequences are $$1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,\dots$$ and $$1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,\dots$$ then both have finitely many terms that occur just once but their sum $$2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\dots$$ has infinitely many terms that occur exactly once.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you.